# Insertion Sort not working

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm new to C and we're supposed to make a program that does insertion sort. Below is my code:

```
int InsertionSort(int array[], int len)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;
    unsigned int k;
    int temp;

    for (i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && array[i] < array[j-1])
        {
            temp = array[j-1];
            array[j-1] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
            j--;
        }

    }

    for (k = 0; k < len; k++)
        printf("The list at: %d\n", array[k]);
    return *array;
}



int main()
{
    int array[10] = {82, 50, 12, 68, 17, 95, 35, 23};
    int len = 8;
    //SelectionSort(array, len);
    InsertionSort(array, len);


}
```

The sorted list is supposed to look like this:

```
[12, 17, 23, 35, 50, 68, 82, 95]
```

But instead, my list looks like this when I print it out:

```
[50, 12, 68, 17, 82, 35, 23, 95]
```

I tried going along with my program on paper with a pencil and it seemed alright, but I guess it isn't working... so I was wondering if anyone could help point out where I went wrong in my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: learning to use a debugger is very helpful for these kind of things.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how exactly do I use a debugger?

Comment: It depends on your OS and development tools. IDEs usually have this built in, and on linux you could also use gdb. With a debugger, you can step through your program line by line and evaluate the variable to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these lines of code

```
while (j > 0 && array[i] < array[j-1])
{
    temp = array[j-1];
    array[j-1] = array[i];
    array[i] = temp;
    j--;
}
```

to

```
while (j > 0 && array[j - 1] > array[j])
{
    temp = array[j];
    array[j] = array[j - 1];
    array[j - 1] = temp;
    j--;
}
```